# cambiar radio button por una imagen

Tags: html, css

Necesito cambiar un radio-button por una imagen.

```
<div class="column-2 filter-options-content  fixed-height ">
<div class="content-to-scroll">
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="option_115">
            <input id="option_115" name="filter_22" type="radio" data-id_searcher="2" data-id_filter="22" data-control_type="2" value="115" checked="">
            <span>Bolt In</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="option_116">
            <input id="option_116" name="filter_22" type="radio" data-id_searcher="2" data-id_filter="22" data-control_type="2" value="116">
            <span>Weld In</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

He usado este CSS pero no consigo ningún cambio:

```
#option_115{   
    background-image: url(img/radio.png);   
    width: 152px;   
    height 
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Los `<input type="radio">`, como casi todos los `<input>` dependen del navegador y/o Sistema Operativo donde se ejecuten para renderizarse. ¿Qué significa esto? Que se ven diferentes dependiendo del navegador, por lo que alterarlos directamente con **CSS** no suele arrojar buenos resultados.

Por lo que se suele optar es por "simularlos" con elementos que si que se pueden alterar mediante **CSS**, teniendo "escondido" el `<input>` para que funcione "desde las sombras" y siendo "marcado/desmarcado" con **Javascript**.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.control-radio-personalizado').click(function () {
    let input_radio = $(this).prev('.radio-personalizado');
    
    if (input_radio.not(':checked')) {
      input_radio.prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
  
  $('.control-radio-personalizado-imagen').click(function () {
    let input_radio = $(this).prev('.radio-personalizado');
    
    if (input_radio.not(':checked')) {
      input_radio.prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.grupo-control-radio-personalizado {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.radio-personalizado {
    display: none;
}

.control-radio-personalizado:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #dae1ea;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-personalizado:checked + .control-radio-personalizado:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 17px;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 17px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    background: #1F74BB;
}

.radio-personalizado:checked + .control-radio-personalizado-imagen:before {
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/752923302000295936/QP7SrVMv_400x400.jpg');
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.control-radio-personalizado-imagen:before {
  background-image: url('https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190124/ourlarge/pngtree-x-red-cross-png-picture-red-png-image_550969.jpg');
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grupo-control-radio-personalizado">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-personalizado" name="miRadio" checked="checked">
  <label class="control-radio-personalizado">Mi radio personalizado 1</label>
</div>

<div class="grupo-control-radio-personalizado">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-personalizado" name="miRadio">
  <label class="control-radio-personalizado">Mi radio personalizado 2</label>
</div>

<div class="grupo-control-radio-personalizado">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-personalizado" name="miRadio">
  <label class="control-radio-personalizado-imagen">Mi radio personalizado 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Si quisieras una imagen podrías añadirle al `:before` un `background-image: url('ruta_de_la_imagen');`, pero la esencia es la misma, un contenedor que simula el `<input>` y controlarlo mediante **JS**.

Comment: Edité la respuesta para añadir un `radio` con imagen.

Comment: 1


Gracias por la respuesta, pero lo q necesito es mostrar una imagen para el radio option_115 y otra distinta para el radio option_116. Se trata de un selector para dos kits distintos y mi cliente quiere mostrar una imagen para cada de kit